# Como apontar o entity framework para outro banco?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

Ola,

Meu Entity Framework aponta sempre para o meu banco local...já tentei mudar a connection string passando os dados de um banco que está em outro servidor e nada acontece ele continua apontando local mesmo se eu comentar a connectionString

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ProjetoZeus-20151023162720;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ProjetoZeus-20151023162720.mdf" />
```

Alguém sabe como posso resolver isso ?

Web Config completo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />  
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ProjetoZeus-20151023162720;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ProjetoZeus-20151023162720.mdf" />

  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Index" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Classe que herda o DBContext

```
public class Contexto : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Pedido> Pedidos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Pais> Paises { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Estado> Estados { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Cidade> Cidades { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Fornecedor> Fornecedores { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Endereco> Endereco { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ItemPedido> Itens { get; set; }

    }
```

objeto Contexto:

```
Contexto context = new Contexto();
```

Comment: Poste o `web.config` ou `app.config` completo.

Comment: editado na pergunta

Answer (score 2):

Não tem muito segredo. Pro SQL Server, por exemplo, basta apontar para a instância e retirar a referência ao nome do arquivo, porque bases do SQL Server tradicionais não usam arquivos:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ProjetoZeus;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Aqui estou considerando que você instalou o SQL Server Express.

Comment: Cigano...eu quero apontar para um server da amazon novo que eu peguei agora pouco...preciso passar o Initial Catalog ?...queria que ele criasse as tabelas automatico...Code First

Comment: Se a Amazon criou o database pra você, sim, precisa.

Comment: eu comentei a connectionString que tava apontando local e coloquei outra de acordo com essa que você mandou...mas continua apontando local rs

Comment: Tem alguma coisa errada aí. Você por um acaso não forçou uma *Connection String* no `DbContext`?

Comment: pior que não...editei la na pergunta pra voce ver como que to usando

Comment: Muito esquisito. Está tudo certo. Veja como fica o `web.config` após a publicação.

Comment: web.config ta igual o de cima ai...só ta diferente aqui <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ProjetoZeus-20151023162720;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ProjetoZeus-20151023162720.mdf" />-->
      <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ProjetoZeus;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
    
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Bom, não sei o que é. Ainda acho que é alguma coisa de configuração.

Comment: É estranho demais ne

Answer (score 1):

Como você disse nos comentários você está apontando para um servidor da Amazon, não sei se é no mesmo de sua aplicação, mas tente utilizar essa `connectionString`:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER\INSTANCIA;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME;Persist Security Info=True;         User ID=USUARIO;Password=SENHA;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

[Neste link](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/) possui alguns exemplos diversos para `connectionStrings`.

Answer (score -1):

Se a sua aplicação estiver dividida em camadas pode ser que na camada de persistência você tenha um arquivo app.config com uma string de conexão adicional. Isso acontece em alguns casos dependendo de como você criou o modelo.

Pode ser que isso esteja forçando o apontamento sempre para o banco local.

Comment: Cara, blz. Acabei de criar minha conta e não sabia que a comunidade era só para os veteranos, inclusive acho que comunidade nenhuma se constrói assim. Além do mais, pelo que analisei da pergunta realmente acredito que possa ser isso, uma string de conexão a mais no app.config que o cara pode não ter percebido que existia, foi uma tentativa de ajudar alguém a resolver um problema, afinal o cara só perguntou como alterar o banco que a aplicação dele está apontando, pois mesmo comentando a string no web.config a aplicação continuou apontando para o banco local, não precisaria de mais informações.